# Layer borderColor and borderWidth is not working for UIButton

Tags: objective-c, colors, uibutton

I have a requirement to add border color and width to `UIButton`. I have tried adding `layer` `borderColor` and `borderWidth` to `button` in code and in storyboard as well.
But its not working in anyway. I have added `QuartzCore` framework in build settings as well.

This is my code to set `bordercolor` and width:

```
self.accountButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
self.accountButton.layer.borderWidth = 6.0f;
```

Can someone please help me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: could u show me what actually u want to acheive in terms of design

Comment: Where exactly are you adding the code? Are you sure your button reference is not nil ?

Comment: I created a property for button.    @property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *continueButton;
Also, link the reference of button in storyboard. It is not nil. I have put these lines to change bordercolor in viewwillappear method

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way, you can customize the width and height to the way you want it latter:

```
[self.<your_Button>.layer setCornerRadius:self.<your_Button>.frame.size.height/2]; 

[self.<your_Button>.layer setCornerRadius:self.<your_Button>.frame.size.width/2]; //
[self.<your_Button>.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
[self.<your_Button>.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
```

Comment: The code used by OP is correct. It doesn't make any difference by calling the setter method! OP hasn't provided much info.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers. I created a category on CALayer class with method

```
- (void)setBorderColorFromUIColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self.borderColor = color.CGColor;
}
```

and then in storyboard, put the run time attribute 
layer.borderColorFromUIColor

that's all and happy Me :)